# Visual Studio 2013 VC++ Compiler

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, msvc12

I am working Visual Studio 2013 and boost 1.60.

When I try to build a project, an error occurred, as seen below:

boost\type_traits\common_type.hpp(42): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

After googling around, it seems that, there is a bug in VC compiler, as explained in the following link:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11885

The solution suggested is to update Visual Studio, which leads to updating MSVC.

However, after I updated Visual Studio to update 5, it seems that the MSVC is not updated, the version of MSVC is still 18.00.21005.1, which is supposed to be updated to 18.00.31101. Therefore, the error happened in the compiling is still there.

Is there anything I have missed? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the preprocessor definition add `BOOST_NO_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIASES`. Which will make this error disappear

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It´s 100% necessary to use VS 2013? Can you change to VS 2015?
If the answer it´s no, you can try to dessinstall and reinstall the VS 2013 and in the instalation process you must be sure to choose the C/C++ compiler, but I think that that compiler it´s obligatory so maybe you have a Installation problem with the compiler, try to reinstall VS .
I hope that this answer will help you.
Regards my friend.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Since VS 2013 was installed by our IT team, it is apparently not easy for me to uninstall the current one and re-install VS 2013 or install VS 2015. From some posts, it seems that, if you install VS 2013 update 5, MSVC should also be updated. But it seems not the case here. I wonder whether there is a way to upgrade MSVC directly.

Comment: MSVC is Microsoft Visual Studio Code? If the answer is yes , you can download form the official web page, the actual version is the 1.2.

Comment: Also you can try to talk again with your IT Team(Sorry ,English isn´t mi first language so I don´t know what mens.)

Comment: Thanks @F.Stan. I guess MSVC stands for Microsoft Visual C++. Is there a way to download and upgrade msvc?